# How to achieve Observable behaviour in vanila js

Tags: javascript, oop, observable, prototype

I am trying to achieve knockout observe computed behavior in vanila js

In react, you will have both these variables on state and compute the fullname

How can we achieve the same in vanila js

```js
function person(firstname,lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.fullName = `${this.firstname}${this.lastname}`
}

var person1 =new person("abc","k");
Object.defineProperty(person,'firstname',{

  get: () => {
      return person1['firstname'];
  },
  set: (name) => {
      person1['firstname'] = name;
  }
  
});
Object.defineProperty(person,'lastname',{

  get: () => {
      return person1['lastname'];
  },
  set: (name) => {
      person1['lastname'] = name;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(person,'fullName',{
  
  get: () => { 
    return `${person1['firstname']}-${person1['lastname']}`;
  }
  
});
console.log(person1.firstname, "firstnmae");
person1.firstname ="sah";
console.log(person1.lastname, "lastname");
console.log(person1.fullName, "fullname");
```

Comment: but i want it to get effected to the changes that we make to firstname and lastname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this code:

```js
var person = {

    firstname: 'abc',
    lastname: 'k'

};

Object.defineProperty(person,'fullName',{
  
    get: function() {
    
        return `${this['firstname']}-${this['lastname']}`;
    
    }

});

var person1 = Object.create( person );

console.log(person1.firstname, "firstnmae");
person1.firstname ="sah";
console.log(person1.lastname, "lastname");
console.log(person1.fullName, "fullname");
```

1. there's no need defining `firstname` and `lastname` by `.defineProperty` because those **setter** and **getter** will work by default as you wrote them.
2. you should use this syntax, as it's easier to read/maintain afterward, otherwise, if you would like to stick to that *constructor* syntax, here you go:

```js
var person = function() {};

Object.defineProperty(person,'firstname',{

    value: 'abc',
    writable: true

});

Object.defineProperty(person,'lastname',{

    value: 'k',
    writable: true

});

Object.defineProperty(person,'fullName',{
  
    get: function() {
    
        return `${this['firstname']}-${this['lastname']}`;
    
    }

});

var person1 = Object.create( person );

console.log(person1.firstname, "firstnmae");
person1.firstname ="sah";
console.log(person1.lastname, "lastname");
console.log(person1.fullName, "fullname");
```

3. I think you need more investigation about [`Object.create()` and MDN is the best place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).
4. [arrow-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have *lexical* `this`, be careful!
5. this syntax maybe clarifies some points about `Object.create()` for you:

```js
var person = function() {};

person.prototype.firstname = 'abc';
person.prototype.lastname = 'k';

Object.defineProperty(person.prototype,'fullName',{
  
    get: function() {
    
        return `${this['firstname']}-${this['lastname']}`;
    
    }

});

var person1 = Object.create( person.prototype );

console.log(person1.firstname, "firstnmae");
person1.firstname ="sah";
console.log(person1.lastname, "lastname");
console.log(person1.fullName, "fullname");
```

Comment: @Geeky glad it helped <3

Comment: That's all good as `OOLO` design is much simpler to maintain than `prototypal`. However, `writable` property is `true` by default so no need to rewrite. :) Good explanation

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti Thanks <3. I'm not sure what does **OOLO* stand for? but [`writable` is false by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description)

Comment: @mrReiha I apologize for the wrong info however it's `OLOO` thats stands for `Object Linked to Other Objects`.

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti no problem <3. never heard of `OLOO` tho xD